How to add html class on each table row, for resources list view in Sulu admin UI
I've created entity, with controller and Admin class, form details and list.
Entities are correctly shown in one html table in Sulu admin area. The question is: is there a way to add html class on each row of this table? Based on entity value (status flag)

Yes. What have you tried?

I tried to modify Sulu react component found here https://jsdocs.sulu.io/2.5/
I just need to add html data-* to row in list view of my doctrine entities according to each entity on the list. But it's built with react Table sulu component. Should I write the entire template?

Please provide the html skeleton you describe in your question post inside a codeblock along with the initial question. This way it is easier for people to help.

Reference: [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. Just stating "is there a way to" and then linking to some documentation, without any context about your own code or situation isn't considered a useful question here.

In sulu you are doing this not on a row level. Instead on a column level on a column level you have different "list transformers" you can create own list transformers as shown in the Sulu Demo here:
https://github.com/sulu/sulu-demo/pull/80
Or use existing list transformer. One option would be the "icon" list transformer.
As example the activity log icon: https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/2.6.6/src/Sulu/Bundle/ActivityBundle/Resources/config/lists/activities.xml#L36-L80

Perfect! Thanks that's what I was looking for

A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable, and/or provide a code example which is relevant to the OP's scenario. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted. See also [answer]. Thanks.
